# how to mock the Bluetooth adapter using any mocking Api for junit

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, bluetooth, mockito

I am trying to write junit test cases for my Bluetooth Code testing in android .
My public method tries to call the buletooth adapter but its giving error like java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getDefaultAdapter in android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter not mocked.

any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BluetoothAdapter in the Android framework is declared final, so it cannot be mocked using Mockito or Robolectric. However, it is possible using PowerMock. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/riis/AndroidArduino/blob/master/libs/ExternalDeviceTest/src/com/riis/androidarduino/lib/test/BluetoothCommTest.java).

Comment: HI SoruoshA, i have been trying to mock the BluetoothAdapter using power mock. but for getting the devices (bonded devices) , its giving the null pointer excpetion. Although i am also mocking the adapter.getbonded dependency. Is there any working example that can be referred

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it helped you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However in my case i have to Inject the mocks to make it work. :)